Secrets in domain distributed powershell scripts
I am working a script for monitoring connection quality to certain websites.
The script will be running via a Group policy in our domain, and should send information to a log analytics workspace.
On multiple different devices, with different users, at 1-4 hours intervals and should not be noticable by the end-user
My issue is, how do i handle the log analytics key in this case?
I looked into the following solutions:
Powershell secret management module: Requires the secret to be encrypted/decrypted on the same device, as this is used on multiple different devices, this didnt seem like a solution to me.
Azure keyvault: Requires the user to logon, and even a silent login, flashes a white window for the user. With this command: Connect-AzAccount -AccountID 'UPN'
Lastpass: we use lastpass as password manager, but only for limited users.
What am i missing, is there any good way to handle the log analytics workspace key, to not include it in the powershell script itself?

As you apparently found out yourself, trying to script a single factor authentication either ends up in a catch-22 or isn't secure as everybody that has access to your script has access to the key no matter how deep you to hide it using security through obscurity. Bottom line:

The general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or Windows authentication, see: How to securely store a password for a script run every day using a Windows task scheduler? for a possible alternative
